# Is it dangerous to use special (0-31) ASCII character in a string?

Tags: string, text, compression, ascii

I am building a string compressor and for simplicity reasons, I wanted to use some non-printable characters. 
1) Is it in some way "bad" to use the 0-31 ASCII characters?
2) Can these characters occur in a normal text string?

If the answer is "partially":
3) What of them is better to use in this case? I think I will need maximum 9 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is that it depends on how you're using it.  If you're treating the "string" as binary, then binary by definition can have any value.  However if it is meant to be read/printed, it could cause serious problems to use characters 0-31.

It isn't too big a deal for the most part, except that 0 is "end of string" by many platforms.  Though again, it depends entirely on how you're using it.  My advice would be at the very least, avoid character 0.  If you want the user to be able to copy and paste the string, then none of these would be suitable.  They must be printable characters, in other words.

Comment: I have added some 16-27 chars. No Problem so far.